Can I use the same package name on Google Play Store?
I have a developer account on Google Play since 2018.
Currently I am experiencing some verification issues and Google support does not react on my requests. Also, my all apps have been removed from Google Play Store.
I decided to create a new developer account and transfer or reupload the same apps onto the new developer account and thus, publish them again by using the same package names. There is no problem with apps, only with developer account.
I think, if I will upload them again, Google would not delete them again. Is that correct?

It's been a bit since I've published a mobile app, but I do remember package names being unique as I do vaguely remember accidentally attempting to publish a com.example package and it was already published. I would think if your app was deleted you might be okay, but maybe the package name is still stored? -- why not just change the package name to be sure? In either case, if you feel your account should not have been removed and you followed policy correctly, you do need to be sure that you get with support so it doesn't happen again

The support does not react on my requests. The apps are ok, but not the account itself and I can't fix that issue. I would publish the same apps with different package name, but one app stores a databank in its package on device and the same app with different package name will not allow users to retrieve stored information from the local database.

I can see you are a real developer based on your profile so I'm not going to try and point out the obvious, but Google Developer Console has support and you can chat with a rep. You pay to be a developer thus you get support. Please follow this link, fill out the form and select "chat" as the contact method: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp?hl=en I only have issues occasionally with GSuite, but I am nearly always able to get support on a chat in 5 or so min

Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately, the Google's support doesn't respond to my requests. That's why I am trying to get any answer on this platform hoping that some has already had experience with package names and can help me out.

Same problem is happening to me. They rejected my identification docs, have been requesting for an explanation and what other options I may have but they have been unresponsive for over a week now. Kinda stuck and so unfair.

Hi All, thank you for your reacts on my questions. I got some updates for you regarding my problem. Google answered on request and helped to transfer apps into new dev account. Now they are again avalaible on Google play and the new account is verfified well.
